# Does FalcorJS router support returning promises?

Tags: falcor, falcor-router

In the examples (as far as I can tell, maybe I missed some subtlety in the router examples), raw values are returned from the get function. Is there  a way to return a callback or promise in the get function? What's the best way to do that?

For now, I'm guessing I use Q.defer?

Answer (score 2):

Examples in the Falcor Router documentation **are** using promises. For instance:

```
{
    route: 'user.["name", "surname"]',
    get: function(pathSet) {
        // pathSet is ["user", ["name"]] or ["user", ["surname"]] or ["user", ["name", "surname"]]
        if (this.userId == null) {
            throw new Error("not authorized");
        } 
        return userService.
            get(this.userId).
            then(function(user) {
                // pathSet[1] is ["name"] or ["surname"] or ["name", "surname"]
                return pathSet[1].map(function(key) {
                    return { path: ["user", key], value: user[key] };
                });
            });
    }
}
```

`userService.get` is returning a promise and is not a directly consumable value. So anything that complies with the promise spec will do.

Comment: Okay, maybe I misunderstand something fairly basic, then. I'm hitting ElasticSearch and I'm trying to return from its then function, but the Router's get function continues to run. What I'm having to do is use deferred to resolve after Elastic returns and then return the promised value from Router.get. If I don't use deferred then the code continues to run and doesn't return in elastic.get().then().